# How to use box shadow in css?

Tags: css

Hello I want to use box shadow for div.
Any idea how to do that ?

I have use

```
box-shadow:         3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
```

but not working in firefox.

Comment: try `-moz-box-shadow`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use :

```
-moz-box-shadow:    3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
  box-shadow:         3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
```

following documents shows it perfectly :

[1](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/)

[2](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/)

[3](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/beautiful-ui-styling-with-css3-text-shadow-box-shadow-and-border-radius/)

Comment: never mind, try after 10 minutes and accept it shows that's why question will accepted and other can't see as unsolved..

Answer (score 0):

Please use `-moz-` prefix for older version of firefox.

```
-moz-box-shadow:     3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc; /*will work only in firefox*/
 box-shadow:         3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc; /*will work on all browser and latest firefox also*/
```

Check it out [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow).

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow

Certain versions of Firefox may still require the use of the `-moz` prefix. Could that be the issue?

```
-moz-box-shadow:         3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
```

Answer (score 0):

This [looks fine to me](http://jsfiddle.net/xfhLv/1/)

```
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 3px #cccccc;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 3px #cccccc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-moz-box-shadow:         3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
```

Check the [MDN for reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to using in mozilla using tag `-moz-box-shadow:..` 
 if chrome using tag `-webkit-box-shadow:..` 
 or in opera using tag `-o-box-shadow:...`
 for more details open

 http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_image_gallery

Comment: I think many of us here dont like the reference of www.w3schools.com as it is not considered good

Answer (score 0):

for inner box-shadow use this

```
 -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #f00;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #f00;
  box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px #f00;
```

And for outer box-shadow use this

```
  -moz-box-shadow:    3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
  box-shadow:         3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
box-shadow:3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
-webkit-box-shadow:3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
-moz-box-shadow:3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
-o-box-shadow:3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
-ms-box-shadow:3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
```

Use this code useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just use it: http://css3gen.com/box-shadow/
It saves a lot of time.